# The object flips after 180 degree of rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I  m new to OpenGL. I have a viewer for a point cloud. 
When I rotate the point cloud around x-axis or z-axis , it gets flipped or inverted after 180 degrees and flips back again at 0 degrees. 
From 0-180 degrees it works fine and from 180-360 degrees it flips.

The following is a code snippet for the paint event

```
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    m_center[0] = (m_minX+m_maxX)/2.0f;
    m_center[1] = (m_minY+m_maxY)/2.0f;
    m_center[2] = (m_minZ+m_maxZ)/2.0f;
    m_radius = static_cast<float>(std::sqrt((m_maxX-m_center[0])*(m_maxX-m_center[0])
        +(m_maxY-m_center[1])*(m_maxY-m_center[1])+(m_maxZ-m_center[2])*(m_maxZ-m_center[2])));
    m_fDistance = m_radius/0.57735f; //where 0.57735f is tan(30 degrees)
    m_dNear = m_fDistance - 3*m_radius;
    m_dFar = m_fDistance + 3*m_radius;

    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
//  glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-m_zoomFactor*2*m_radius, +m_zoomFactor*2*m_radius, -m_zoomFactor*2*m_radius, +m_zoomFactor*2*m_radius, m_dNear, m_dFar);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glRotatef(m_modelRotation.x/16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(m_modelRotation.y/16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);   
    glRotatef(m_modelRotation.z/16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(m_modelScale.x,m_modelScale.y,m_modelScale.z);
    switch(m_shapeMode)
    {
    case eShapePointCloud:
        drawPoints();
        break;
    case eShapeSolid:
        drawQuads();
        break;
    default:
        qDebug()<<"No shape is specified, so use the points shape.";
        drawPoints();
        break;
    }
    glPopMatrix();
```

Here is the code for the mouse move event

```
    void OglWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
GLfloat dx = GLfloat(event->x() - m_lastPos.x()) ;/// width();
GLfloat dy = GLfloat(event->y() - m_lastPos.y()) ;/// height();

if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) 
{
    setXRotation(m_modelRotation.x + 8*dy);
    setZRotation(m_modelRotation.z + 8*dx);

    this->setPropertyValue(1,m_modelRotation);

} 

m_lastPos = event->pos();
    }
```

Comment: How about you show us some code related to your problem? It's not like "object flips after 180 degree" is such a common problem that we immediately know what's going on. At least I don't.

Comment: Two things striking me odd in your code: You have a glLoadIdentity and glPushMatrix before setting matrix mode to GL_PROJECTION; the problem with this is, that it's completely undefined (in your code snippet) which matrix they're acting upon. I'd presume they are for the modelview matrix, which you switch to later. I suggest you move the glLoadIdentity glPushMatrix between `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` and the first glRotate. –– the second thing is more about readability: The point cloud is your default shape mode. So just write `switch(m_shapeMode){ default: case eShapePointCloud: …}`

Comment: @datenwolf the changes that you said were implemeted. Thanks. But i still have the problem of the flip . The movement of the mouse is alos affected , i.e after 180 degress of rotation if i move the mouse in x direction the object moves in -x direction till 360 degrees .

Comment: @user31351: That sounds then a lot like a problem with the mouse input handler. It's really hard to tell without seeing all of your code. Also pictures / screenshots would help a lot.

Comment: @datenwolf: Does this has to do something with the GIMBAL lock?

Comment: @user31351: It might do, but normally gimbal lock makes an object "stuck" in a particular axis and doesn't flip it. OTOH your use of Euler rotations is prone to gimbal lock.

Comment: @datenwolf : If i move in X direction -after 180 degree rotation the object flips in z direction and if I move in z direction after 180 degree rotation in Z direction the object flips in X direction